# Azure Front Door doesn't redirect to specify App Function

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I want to create Front Door serwice who split traffic between App Function instances. I have three App Function services, and in each of them a function called Function1. Unfortunately, I cannot set App Function (Function 1) as endpoints:

**Case I:**
I create one pool and add three backend as **App Service** (Backend host type) and select my App Function. However, there is a problem because FrontDoor redirects traffic to the home page of the service and not to the given function (Function1). I decided to create a proxy in each App Function service, but I get a message that ***"Proxy is not available for V4 Function App"***

**Case II:**
I create pool and i want to add Function endpoint as **Custom Host** (Backend host type) but i can add as endpoint only FQDN domain endpoint while function endpoint is:
https://[function-name].azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=[code]

Comment: The most easy way is to scale out your app service instance. That way, the split traffic is handled by the app service internal load balancer. If you want to split the traffic to multiple regions, you create an app service in each region and add them as backend pools in frontdoor.

Comment: @JackPoint it's not clear the reason to route to different functions is related to split the workload.

Comment: Is there any update to this question? Even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @coffeeguy I am not resolve this problem